# How do I define trait bounds on an associated type?

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types

I want to write a function that accepts `Iterator` of type that has `ToString` trait.

What I have in mind:

```
fn parse<T: Iterator /* ?T::Item : ToString? */>(mut args: T) -> Result<String, String> {
    match args.next() {
        Some(x) => x.to_string(),
        None => String::from("Missing parameter"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with a `where` clause:

```
fn parse<T: Iterator>(mut args: T) -> Result<String, String>
where 
    <T as Iterator>::Item: ToString,
{
   // ....
}
```

Or, since it's unambiguous which `Item` is meant here, the bound can just be:

```
where T::Item: ToString
```

Comment: Thanks! How is the `<T as Iterator>::Item` part called? I was not able to google it, since I was probably missing the correct terminology.

Comment: That part doesn't have a name by itself (I don't think), but `T::Item: ToString` is called a _bound_, or a _trait bound_. You might also see it called a _constraint_.

Answer (score 14):

You can  use the [`Item =` syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/associated-types.html#trait-objects-with-associated-types):

```
fn parse<I: ToString, T: Iterator<Item = I>>(mut args: T) -> Result<String, String>
```

That allows you to simplify this further with the `impl` syntax:

```
fn parse<T: Iterator<Item = impl ToString>>(mut args: T) -> Result<String, String>
```

and finally:

```
fn parse(mut args: impl Iterator<Item = impl ToString>) -> Result<String, String>
```

I would consider this a more readable alternative.